# Angular call a controller specific function every time that a specific $state is hit

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a wait screen with a timeout on a state.
I want the $timeout to be called everytime the user goes to that state.

Something like the function bellow:

```
function LoadingController($scope,$state,$timeout){
    this.$state=$state;
    var self=this;

    if(this.handleStateValidity()){
        var timeOutFn=function(){
            self.goToRedirectUrl();
        }
        $timeout(timeOutFn,2000);

    }
});
```

Of course this is only being called once the controller is first loaded. How can i detect subsequent hits to the state that this controller is concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was execute the function on the link of the directive or controller initialization the first time. And then start listening for the state.
Hopefuly there is a better way to do it as this way i thought to be a little "dirty":

```
    var timeOutFn=function(){
        self.goToRedirectUrl();
    }
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    if(toState.name=='loading'){
        $timeout(timeOutFn,2000);
    }
    });
    $timeout(timeOutFn,2000);
```